# Dropdown Menu in Monogame/XNA

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, xna, monogame

I'm working on a game and developing the Main Menu, in there I have a settings scene. This scene contains a few tabs and for the video tab, I would like a dropdown menu that allows the switching of resolutions. Now, the latter part I understand the logic for, but using the XNA framework I am failing to understand the logic of a drop down menu. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually made a DropDown for my game, it really isn't that hard when you think about it. First you'll need a `DropDownContainer` class and a `DropDownElement`. The `DropDownContainer` is the top part of the DropDown where you see the currently selected option. The `DropDownElement`s are the selectable options you show when the user clicks on `DropDownContainer`.

Here is how the code works:

1. Create an array of `DropDownElement`s in your `DropDownContainer` class.
2. In the constructor of `DropDownContainer`, pass the number of `DropDownElement`s and an array of strings where each string is the text of specific `DropDownElement`.
3. Make the `DropDownElement`'s constructor take a string and in it's `Draw(spriteBatch)` method, draw that string over the texture of the `DropDownElement`.
4. Pass in a `Vector2` as position for the container, it will be used as a base to position the elements too. Example loop in `DropDownContainer`'s constructor:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
   {
       elements[i] = new DropDownElement(spriteFont, textArray[i], new Vector2(containerPosition.X, (containerPosition.Y + (34 * (i + 1))) + 2), this.textColor, content); // 34 = DropDownElement's Texture height
   }
   ```
5. Make sure you pass in a `ContentManager content` in both classes's constructors so you can load your assets.
6. Have a bounding `Rectangle` for both of these classes, where it's `X` and `Y` are `(int)containerPosition.X, (int)containerPosition.Y` and `Width` and `Height` are the dimensions of the `Texture2D`.
7. In `DropDownContainer`'s `Update(gameTime)` method, have a check if the cursor is within the `bounds` and if the user clicks change a flag like this: `clicked = !clicked;`
8. In `DropDownContainer`'s `Draw(spriteBatch)` method, check `if (clicked)` and draw the `elements` array by looping through it.
9. Instantiate the DropDown like this: `private DropDownContainer dropDown = new DropDownContainer(...);` and call it's corresponding methods.
10. To check which option was selected, just expose the `Text` property of the `DropDownElement`s.
11. When you are done with that you can add things like mouse hover effects and text color fading in/out using linear interpolation.

I also made a TextBox for my XNA game but that deals with some heavy P/Invokes and since you don't know how to make a basic Drop Down it would be too complicated to explain.

**Edit to address the comment below:**

There are a few problems with your logic, I'll highlight them:

1. Without a `string` property that gets/sets the text of the elements, how would you check which element was selected? E.g. `if (container.Text == "text of first element") { /* user chose the lowest resolution */ }`
2. Unless you pass the text to the constructor there is no way to set the `Element`'s text, if there is no `Text` property.
3. How would you add the value `1600x900` directly to an `enum`? Unless I misunderstand you, there's no way you could put a `string` (1600x900 is a string) in an `enum`...

Even if you were to do something like this:

```
enum resOptions
{
    _800x600 = 0,
    _1280x1024 = 1,
    _1920x1080 = 2,
    // etc.
}
```

And maybe have them ordered the same way in the `DropDownElement` array, but still, you'll have to implement your own way to see which option the user clicked on... Which eventually will lead you to checking the `Text` property of the `DropDownContainer`.

So I would advice strongly against using an `enum` here because it would only over-complicate the already complex enough DropDown algorithm. It would take you much more time to write a way to check what option was selected.

I would just set the `Container`'s `Text` to the clicked `Element`'s `Text` on user click and that's how I would check the selected option. If you are still willing to do this with an `enum`, I'm afraid I won't be of much help because I already gave you a hint on how to do it the simple way. If you want to do it another way, you'll have to write the code for it yourself. After all the idea of this site is not "Write my code for me" but rather "Give me a good idea how to properly write it **myself**".

Over-complicating things when you can just do it with both less effort and less code is bad programming practice. Only if you plan to extend the `DropDown`'s functionality, making it complex is good. But in your case I honestly don't see a point to set `Text` like this. Why would you discard the simple yet effective solution and pursue something you are not sure about?

If you have further questions, feel free to comment.

Comment: I have a slight idea here. Instead of using the Text property of the dropdown elements, could I instead create an enumerator of default resolution scales (e.g. 1600x900) and set it to the value of that? And then of course allow the user to input their own custom resolution if need be.

Comment: @Matttheawesome1 , I edited the answer to address your question. If you have further questions, feel free to comment.

Comment: Ah I feel silly now, forgot that enums can't use strings. Why is that, if anyone knows. Or can link me to another question.

Comment: `enum` literally means E***num***erator. Were it designed with `string` values in mind, it would have been called something else. I believe what you were looking for is a `Dictionary<int, string>` that would store your `string Text` under the specified `int Key`. As I said before, this complicates things and needlessly creates a collection of objects which can be avoided. That's why I like passing arguments to the constructor more...

Comment: No no, I'm listening to your answer here now, and thank you for your explanation. I simply forgot that enumeraters can't use strings. Thank you for this, good day.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using existing UI library. Instead of trying to implement advanced UI system from scratch.

Nice UI library: [Empty Keys](http://emptykeys.com/ui_library)

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, however, as I am in a classroom environment, unfortunately, I cannot download third party libraries to this machine without the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this as a drop down menu.

That is a very mouse/keyboard centric ui element. Consider how a user would interact with this if playing with a controller.

Even if you have no plans of this game being playable with a controller, you may find that avoiding complex ui elements like a drop-down menu makes it easier for you to continue prototyping rather than being distracted by UI.

Proposed solution:
Upon choosing the menu item representing "change resolution from NxM" replace or overlay the current menu with a new submenu for choosing a specific resolution from a vertical list. When it closes, return to the previous menu.